# Sheets not copying data over

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CostPriceMain()

Dim SourceWkb As Workbook
Dim TargetWkb As Workbook
Dim SourceWksht As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

NewFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Files         
(*.xlsx; *.xls), (*.xlsx; *.xls), All Files, *.*", FilterIndex:=1)

If NewFile = False Then Exit Sub
If NewFile <> False Then
Set SourceWkb = Workbooks.Open(NewFile)
End If

Set TargetWkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\WK24.xlsx") ' warning - XLS file could cause problems - see note

For Each SourceWksht In SourceWkb.Worksheets
If SourceWksht.Visible Then
     SourceWkb.Sheets("Price List").Range("C:E").Copy
     TargetWkb.Sheets("Price List").Range("C:E").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
End If

Next SourceWksht

TargetWkb.Close False
SourceWkb.Close False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Done = MsgBox("Task Complete", vbOKOnly)

End Sub
```

My main issue seems to be with

```
       SourceWkb.Sheets("Price List").Range("C:E").Copy
       TargetWkb.Sheets("Price List").Range("C:E").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
```

It running without an issues, but its not actually copying the data over, and I can't seem to work out why
I tried

```
   TargetWkb.Sheets("Price List").Range("A:A").Value = SourceWkb.Sheets("Price 
   List").Range("A:A")
```

Bit still got the same result of no data, any ideas?

Comment: Are you positive the sheet names are correct, and the ranges? Is it not copying the data *or* is that part of the statement not firing? Step through the macro with `F8` to see if it even runs that line.  I *think* the issue may lie in the logic. You're looping through worksheets in the source, but then not doing anything with the visible sheets.

Comment: Why are you looping through the worksheets (e.g. `For Each SourceWksht In SourceWkb.Worksheets` if you are copying a specific worksheet's data?

Answer (score 1):

There are some oddities in your code. Most notably:

```
 'Here you loop through every worksheet in your source workbook
    'but you only copy one specific sheet. This is superfluous and 
    'may be causing the issue (although it shouldn't)
    For Each SourceWksht In SourceWkb.Worksheets
        If SourceWksht.Visible Then
             SourceWkb.Sheets("Price List").Range("C:E").Copy
             TargetWkb.Sheets("Price List").Range("C:E").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        End If
    Next SourceWksht
```

Give this quick rewrite a shot and see if the problem clears up. I have added comments to say what each block of code is doing in case it illuminates any misunderstandings.

```
Sub CostPriceMain()

    Dim SourceWkb As Workbook
    Dim TargetWkb As Workbook       

    'shhh
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'ask user for excel file to source from
    NewFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel File (*.xlsx; *.xls), (*.xlsx; *.xls), All Files, *.*", FilterIndex:=1)

    'Did they pick a file?
    If Not NewFile = False Then 
        Set SourceWkb = Workbooks.Open(NewFile)
    Else 
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Set up the target workbook
    Set TargetWkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\WK24.xlsx") ' warning - XLS file could cause problems - see note

    'Copy the price list from source workbook on the tab called "Price List"
    'For columns C through E. Copying it to the Target Workbook to the tab
    'called "Price List" using the same columns, only copying the values.
    SourceWkb.Sheets("Price List").Range("C:E").Copy
    TargetWkb.Sheets("Price List").Range("C:E").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

    'Clean up
    TargetWkb.Close False
    SourceWkb.Close False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Notify user
    Done = MsgBox("Task Complete", vbOKOnly)

End Sub
```

Comment: This is giving me a syntax error on      NewFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Files

Comment: @JamesPavett Sorry about that. Copy/Paste issue from your original code. I have fixed it.

Comment: Now it seems to be a type mismatch on If NewFile Then.

Comment: Sorry again. Debugging remote here and took a chance on that one. I have updated it and it should be happy now.

Comment: For some reason it worked, but again did not copy the data. I'm starting to wonder if theres an issue with my source file, but I cannot see one at all.

Comment: Can you remove the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` at the top and see if it alerts to anything while running. The code is pretty clear cut, so it doesn't make much sense that it's not copying. Try also tossing a breakpoint (f9) on that `pastespecial` line and see if everything looks good in debug.

Comment: @JamesPavett - Have you stepped through the code with `F8`? That will show you if the copy/paste lines are being run or not.  If they're not being run, then it's an issue with the `IF` statement. If they are being run, but not copying data, we can whittle down more into the reason why.

Comment: @JNevill With the alerts back on, the only popup I get is regarding a large amount of information on the clipboard, could that be causing an issue?

Comment: If you run it step by step it actually works. Do I need a command for saving the target workbook? Or possible a time break if thats what is occuring.